# How to calculate color bounds?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, objective-c++

I'd like to apply some kind of color isolation like you can see in this image:

[image: img]

I've already written some lines that should be able to do this job by using the `inRange() call`:

```
cv::inRange(hsvMat, lower_value, upper_value, colorMask);
```

But I'm not really sure how to set the upper & lower values for the `Scalar bounds` like what I'm doing with:

```
cv::Scalar lower_value(X, X, X);
cv::Scalar upper_value(Y, Y, Y);
```

> The values for the green circle are `r: 109, g: 138, b: 54` but how can I calculate a upper and a lower bound by a given threshold (percentage value)?

```
+(UIImage *)ConvertImage:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat rawImage;
    UIImageToMat(image, rawImage);

    cv::Mat bgrMat;
    cv::cvtColor(rawImage, bgrMat, CV_BGRA2BGR);

    cv::Mat hsvMat;
    cv::cvtColor(bgrMat, hsvMat, CV_BGR2HSV);

    cv::Mat colorMask;

    cv::Scalar lower_value(X, X, X);
    cv::Scalar upper_value(Y, Y, Y);

    cv::inRange(hsvMat, lower_value, upper_value, colorMask);

    cv::Mat output;
    bgrMat.copyTo(output, colorMask);

    UIImage *ret = MatToUIImage(output);
    return ret;
}
```

Any help how to implement / especially how to calculate these values would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why are you converting to hsv?

Comment: Any other ideas? @alhadhrami

Comment: Are you saying that you have a percentage as a given and you want to calculate an upper and lower limits to the RGB values based on that percentage? Example, a 1% is given, therefore the upper and lower limits of the circle color (109, 138, 54) are (110, 139, 55) and (108, 137, 53), respectively (after rounding to nearest).